# Lasik Operation Choice

Tags: eye, lasik

I went to two different eye doctors, both with good reputations, requesting and asking to do a lasik operation on my eyes.

The first one said he would do and "Ultra-lasik" operation, because it is the most recent, quickest and has very low recovery time.

The second one said I needed the original "lasik" operation, because my eyes thankfully have no problems. (He said the original lasik is used with people whose eyes have no problem, femtolasik for people with fewer-than-normal cornea layers, ultralasik for people with even fewer cornea layers, and femto-smile for people that have so few layers that they can't even open the eye flap they open to do the operation (I am not sure of the exact name of this flap)).

**How can I decide which is better?** Each doctor gave 2 entirely different extremes. Does this indicate they are equally good, or that one doctor is wrong? Where can I learn enough to make a good decision?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). We can't recommend you over the internet which operation type to chose, but we could answer a more general question, such as what are the benefits and disadvantages of each type of operation and to back it up with research. You can always [edit] your question to make it more on-topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not my professional area of expertise -- however I had Lasik done years ago when there weren't many "experienced" optometrists to choose from.  The optometrist I saw said he was one of the first in the field to do it.

---

I'm embarrassed to say I paid $6,700 for the procedure *(I guess this post is somewhat a rant as I think I was overcharged)*

After I could see 15/20 bilaterally for years.  So it worked great, however not sure what exactly changed but one eye is now 60/20 and I need glasses after paying that much for the procedure.

---

1.) As you received conflicting information, **see additional professionals until you feel comfortable with their answers.**  The initial consultation is **normally free** as this is an elective surgery.

2.) Again this is just based on my experience having had "Normal Lasik". I can tell you the actual procedure took literally 5 minutes. So unless I'm missing something procedure length should not be a concern.

3.) Make a list of doctors in your area (that specialize in Lasik).  Call and make sure the consultation is free -- go see as many as you want. Come with a list of questions and don't be afraid to politely ask follow up questions (or for them to clarify their reasoning).

---

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

I hope you find the following helpful.
Your first doctor stated he would do Ultra Lasik. He told why it is better, using those benefits as his rationale for the choice. He chose Ultra because of the surgical benefit (thinner flap, shorter recovery time, etc...), not because of any clinical limitations due to your corneas. 
Your second surgeon said you don't have any problems with your cornea, so you don't "need" to have Ultra Lasik. Your first surgeon would definitely have told you if you have a problem with your corneas limiting your Lasik options. So, that is something upon which both of them must agree. The econd surgeon reserves Ultra for patients with issues. It costs more, but they don't have the options you have. Your first surgeon is recommending the superior technique. Money for newer procedure may be part of his motivation, but the fact that Ultra Lasik is better is not in question. If you want the best technique, Ultra Lasik is your answer. You don't "need" it, so spending the extra money isn't necessary if it will be a hardship. Hey, if you choose Ultra, either physician could perform the procedure..OR...having made the clinical decision, you can shop around to optimize price! As a person with the "problem" corneas, I can say you are in an enviable position. Good luck! I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Stackexchange operates somewhat differently than other forums, it is designed as a Q&A website with intention to gather knowledge. Hence, personal opinions are not supported as answers, and on Health reliable references that back up answers are required. Please take our [tour] or visit the [help] for more information on site policies. Thanks!

Comment: -1 for no references